# Scale google signin button on iOS w/ constraints

Tags: ios, uibutton, google-oauth

I am trying to add google login to my iOS application.  The app will go to my nodejs server (using passport to hit google to login).  Long story short I do not need to use the Google iOS sdk for login as I am not going from my to directly to google.

But I do need a correctly styled google signin button.  I found the branding guidelines here:
https://developers.google.com/+/branding-guidelines?hl=en

And they have a download for the iOS icons and a sketch file.  The problem I am running into how do I use that button image and have it scale correctly based on constraints?  IE if I set the image as the background and size the button to be whatever size I want in my view the G+ will also stretch.

[image]

But if I don't set as a background I cannot make the button the correct width.

Is there a way to make the button whatever width I want without stretching the G+ logo?

Next up would be how to get Roboto Text in there as well...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Image Slicing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/chapters/SlicinganImage.html). Below is the steps:

1. Select the image you add in the asset catalog.
2. Choose `Horizontel` in Slicing section of the Attributes Inspecter.
3. Input 35 for Left field, input 5 for Right field. Below is what the slicing looks like:

[image: Slicing]

4. Set the image as a button background in Storyboard or nib.

Now resize the button, the logo will not be streched.